# Equivalent of VecDoub in C?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C++ and was curious what is the C equivalent of Vecdoub and VecInt?
I am trying to evaluate code for LU decomposition but it is written in C++, some of the code is as follows.

```
VecDoub vv(n);
VecInt indx;

vv[i] = 1/max;
```

I am assuming that VecInt is similar to an array and vecdoub is similar to a 2-d array or am I completely wrong?  Any clear and concise information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `VecDoub` in c++? There's no such class supported by the c++ standard.

Comment: Same for `VecInt`.

Comment: Maybe _VecDoub vv(n)_ - is array of n elements of type double. _VecInt indx_ - is array of type int (size not initialized). But it's only my assumption

Comment: I was viewing some information from Numerical Recipes in C and I figured the chunk of code I am looking at was in C++, I am even more perplexed now.

Comment: snake_style - that makes sense too.  I'll have to do some more digging

Comment: make your own opinion, but note that the code in Numerical Recipes is partly outdated and partly even the algorithms they use are rather controversial numerics wise. I love the book for its easy to grasp explanations, but dont take everything for granted what they write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about `VecDoub`, which is a typedef/rename of the type `std::vector<double>` in the book Numerical Recipes.

C doesn't have an STL library like C++, so there's nothing there that you won't have to create yourself from scratch. Even if you plan to do it, you should be proficient C programmer to be able to manage memory correctly. One library I saw implementing such a vector is libbtc. See their implementation [here](https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc/blob/master/include/btc/vector.h) and [here](https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc/blob/master/src/vector.c). You can also see how to use it in the tests [here](https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc/blob/master/test/vector_tests.c).

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I figured I could replicate what I am reading by dynamically allocating memory but so far I've been running into issues.   I'll look into the links you've posted.